# Post request is giving 401 Unauthorized user error with HttpClient Angular 5

Tags: post, angular5, http-status-code-401, angular-httpclient

In my angular 5 application, I am having the get and post requests which are as follows:

Get request:

```
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){
this.httpClient.get(this.url_string,{ withCredentials: true }).subscribe(data => {
this.name = data;  }) }
```

Post Request:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.url_string,this.data_request,{ withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
          data => {
    //doing something with data});
```

In the backend I am using Node service with node-sspi for fetching the username from request.

Node Service :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) { //allow cross origin requests
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost/Sample");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi')
  var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
    retrieveGroups: true
  })
  nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
    res.finished || next()
  })
})


app.get('/sign', function fnn(request, response) {

response.send(request.connection.user);


});

app.post('/upload', function fnn1(request, response) {

//doing something

});
```

My question is all the get request are working fine. But when i use post request I got Error 401 (Unauthorized User).

Some More Info:

I am deploying my angular app using ng buid --prod --base-href /Sample/
and deployed it on IIS on default Site

And on the Same machine I had deployed my Node Service using NSSM.

Please guide me where I am wrong.

Thanks in Advance.